# Find Count Distinct in CakePHP

Tags: sql, cakephp-2.0

This is a simple query problem. But it seems that I can't get it right :( 
I just started using cakephp last week. I'm still playing around exploring. Anyway, here's my problem.

**This is the relationship in Model:** Product has many Stock. Stock belongs to Product.

**This is the sample STOCKS table:**

```
ID  |  Product Name  |  Transaction
------------------------------------
1   |  Astringent    |  Purchase
2   |  Glutathione   |  Sales
3   |  Glutathione   |  Sales
```

I would like to get the number of transaction per product from the STOCKS table.

**This is the output I would like with distinct product name:**

```
Transaction   |  Astringent  |  Glutathione
--------------------------------------------
purchase      |  1           |  0
sales         |  0           |  2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sql query- for *exactly* what you requested.

```
SELECT transaction,
SUM(
CASE
  WHEN product_name = 'Astringent' THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END) AS 'Astringent',
SUM(
CASE
  WHEN product_name = 'Glutathione' THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END) AS 'Glutathione'
FROM stock
GROUP BY transaction;
```

However, are you looking for a pivot table i.e., an output with a variable number of columns based on a random number of products?  If so, your solution is lot more complicated as a MySQL query, and potentially less complicated as a MySQL and PHP solution.  In either case, I think you should share more of your database schema / CakePHP model along with some controller information.  In order to render a view with this table is not overly difficult as long as you want Cakephp to output this format.